# Why $\mathrm{Restriction}\circ \mathrm{Corestriction}$ is multiplication on cohomology?

Tags: group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a subgroup of index $m$.
Let $A$ be a $G$-module. we have restriction $$\mathrm{Res}: H^n(G,A)\to H^n(H,A)$$ and co-restriction
$$\mathrm{Cor}: H^n(H,A)\to H^n(G,A).$$
It is known that
$$\mathrm{Cor}\circ \mathrm{Res}(c)=mc.$$ I don't see why the converse holds:

> Why
> $$\mathrm{Res}\circ \mathrm{Cor}(c)=mc$$ for every $c\in H^n(H,A)$?

In this direction applying Res doesn't do anything to the function, and we stay with some sum $\sum_{i=1}^m g_i f(g_i^{-1}p)$ for every $p\in P_n$ for a projective resolution $P_n$ of $\mathbb Z$ as a $G$-module. The different terms in the sum seem like distrinct functions, and we cannot put the $g_i^{-1}$ outside because $f$ is only a $\mathbb Z H$-module homomorphism.

Here's the claim in Dummit & Foote:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that $f$ is only an $H$-module homomorphism, but in fact it's a $G$-equivariant: we started with a $G$-invariant homomorphism, "forgot" it was $G$-invariant, and then applied the formula with the sums. Since it was $G$-invariant, each term in the formula with the sum is just $f(p)$.

EDIT: as discussed in the comments, the other claim about corestricting and then restricting is false. Reference Neukirch Schmidt and Wingberg Corollary 1.5.7 for the correct formulation.

Comment: Thank you! I now edited the question to exchange the order of restriction and co-restriction. Do you maybe see why this other direction holds?

Comment: @Emolga the proof from Dummit-Foote you have copy/pasted is for the other direction, though, no?

Comment: From $CR = m$ you get formally $RCRC = mRC$; this implies $RC = m$ whenever $RC$ is surjective. However it is not generally true. For example, suppose $H$ is the trivial group and $G$ is the cyclic group of order $2$ with the non-trivial element acting by negation on $M = \mathbb{Z}$. Then $M^G = 0$, $M^H = \mathbb{Z}$, so corestricting and then restricting must act by $0$ on $H^0$ and not multiplication by $2$.

Comment: So it is a mistake in the book?

Comment: sorry, just saw the last line. It's definitely false on H^0.  Do they say anything afterward?

Comment: They don't. (Strange)

Comment: I think in Dummit and Foote it's just a typo for "it follows that Cor \circ Res is mult. by m on the cohomology groups", i.e. they are just saying this descends to cycles mod boundaries. They are not trying to say that this works in the other order (which is false.)